# How to prevent page reoading after switching routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My sidebar uses react-router-dom to switch between page files using routes, however when I switch routes, my page reloads. Is there a way I can switch routes without reloading the page?

SideBar

```
import React from 'react'
import {SideNav_Data} from "./SideNav_Data"
import Sunrise from './Sunrise.png'

function SideNav() {
  return (
    <div className = "SideNav">
        <img src={Sunrise} className='SideNavImg' alt=''/>
        <ul className="SideNavList">
            {SideNav_Data.map((val, key) => {
                return (
                    <li key={key} 
                    className = "row"
                    id={window.location.pathname === val.link ? "active" : ""}
                    onClick = {() => {
                        window.location.pathname = val.link;
                    }}>
                        <div id='icon'>{val.icon}</div>{" "}<div id='title'>{val.title}</div>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SideNav
```

Sidebar Data

```
import React from 'react'
import CottageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Cottage';
import DirectionsCarFilledIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DirectionsCarFilled';
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import AccountBalanceIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountBalance';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';
import ContactSupportIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ContactSupport';

export const SideNav_Data = [
    {
        title: "Home",
        icon: <CottageIcon />,
        link: "/"
    },
    {
        title: "Cars",
        icon: <DirectionsCarFilledIcon />,
        link: "/Cars"
    },
    {
        title: "Representatives",
        icon: <PersonIcon />,
        link: "/Representatives"
    },
    {
        title: "Loan Estimator",
        icon: <AccountBalanceIcon />,
        link: "/Loan-Estimator"
    },
    {
        title: "Account",
        icon: <AccountCircleIcon />,
        link: "/Account"
    },
    {
        title: "Support",
        icon: <ContactSupportIcon />,
        link: "/Support"
    },

]
```

Home page

```
import React from 'react'
import SideNav from '../Components/SideNav'

function Home() {
  return (<div>
    <SideNav />
  </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Cars from './Pages/Cars';
import Reps from './Pages/Reps';
import LoanEst from './Pages/LoanEst';
import Account from './Pages/Account';
import Support from './Pages/Support';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="/Cars" element={<Cars />}/>
        <Route path="/Representatives" element={<Reps />}/>
        <Route path="/Loan-Estimator" element={<LoanEst />}/>
        <Route path="/Account" element={<Account />}/>
        <Route path="/Support" element={<Support />}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I've tried switching the "link: " part of the sidebar data to <Link to={Home /}/> but that resulted in the sidebar completely disappearing.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `Link` component instead of changing `window.location.pathname`:

```
{SideNav_Data.map((val, key) => {
    return (
        <Link 
            key={key} 
            className = "row"
            id={window.location.pathname === val.link ? "active" : ""}
            to={val.link}
        >
            <div id='icon'>{val.icon}</div>{" "}<div id='title'>{val.title}</div>
        </Link>
    )
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

- Using `window.location.pathname` to set the current URL path will necessarily trigger a page reload and remount the entire app. Use one of the link components exported from `react-router-dom` to issue declarative navigation actions within the app.
- The `SideNav` component disappears because it is only rendered when the `Home` component is rendered when the path is `"/"`. Use a layout route to render the `SideNav` component

## Solution

I suggest importing and using the `NavLink` component as it's a special version of the `Link` component that applies an `"active"` classname by default. If you need to compute the `id` attribute for the `li` element then use the `useLocation` hook to access the current `location.pathname` value.

Example:

```
import { NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

function SideNav() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="SideNav">
      <img src={Sunrise} className='SideNavImg' alt='' />
      <ul className="SideNavList">
        {SideNav_Data.map((val) => (
          <li
            key={val.link} 
            className="row"
            id={pathname === val.link ? "active" : ""}
          >
            <NavLink to={val.link} end>
              <div id='icon'>{val.icon}</div>
              {" "}
              <div id='title'>{val.title}</div>
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Render the `SideNav` as part of a layout route so it's conditionally rendered with the routes you want it to be rendered with.

Example:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom"
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Cars from './Pages/Cars';
import Reps from './Pages/Reps';
import LoanEst from './Pages/LoanEst';
import Account from './Pages/Account';
import Support from './Pages/Support';
import SideNav from './Components/SideNav';

const SideNavLayout = () => (
  <>
    <SideNav />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<SidNavLayout />}>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/Cars" element={<Cars />} />
          <Route path="/Representatives" element={<Reps />} />
          <Route path="/Loan-Estimator" element={<LoanEst />} />
          <Route path="/Account" element={<Account />} />
          <Route path="/Support" element={<Support />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Home

```
import React from 'react';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```